# Attempted to load class "TwigExtraBundle" from namespace "Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have the following in my Symfony project's `composer.json` file:

```
...
"twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
...
```

... and the following in my `bundles.php` file:

```
...
Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
...
```

... and when I run `composer install`, everything seems to be installed correctly.

Whenever I load a page, however, I get this error:

> ClassNotFoundException Attempted to load class "TwigExtraBundle" from
> namespace "Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle". Did you forget a "use"
> statement for another namespace? in Kernel.php line 23 at
> Kernel->registerBundles()in Kernel.php line 446 at
> Kernel->initializeBundles()in Kernel.php line 133 at Kernel->boot()in
> Kernel.php line 196 at Kernel->handle(object(SiteRequest))in index.php
> line 32

What step am I missing?

====

Edit: I have so far found the following:

- When running `composer require twig/extra-bundle`, composer says there's nothing to change in `composer.lock`.
- If I remove the `vendor` folder and do a `composer install`, the correct classes seem to appear in the vendor folder, though Symfony pages still can't find them.
- Indeed, I can even use ctrl-b in PHPStorm to jump to the classes in the vendor folder.

Comment: Going from what you have, have you tried `composer dump-autoload` ? Maybe your classes need to be re-scanned for some reason..

Comment: Good advice, but no luck. `composer dump-autoload` didn't do the trick.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you run `composer require` after adding the requirement to the JSON configuration?

Comment: I've tried `composer require` along with removing the vendor folder and redoing a `composer install`. (See other comments)

Comment: And does your `vendor` folder then contain the classes in question? Does `composer.lock` contain the requirement?

Comment: Delete the `vendor/` folder and run a `composer install`

Comment: @the_nuts: I did indeed try that. No luck. @Nico Haase: Good questions. `composer.lock` does indeed contain the requirement, and the classes are present in the `vendor` folder. I can even jump to them from the `bundles.php` file in phpstorm using ctrl-b. So it's just Symfony that's having trouble finding the classes.

Comment: Please add all such clarification to your question by editing

Comment: Although you don't mention that, I suspect you're using Docker and using `composer require...` on the host. That is causing exactly the problem you described. After using `composer install` within the container problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you are using `TwigExtraBundle` (which you didn't show), you might accidentally have something like

```
use Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle;

...

$foo = new TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle();
```

notice the duplication. If I intentionally put code in my class like that, I produce the error you are are seeing.

```
Attempted to load class “TwigExtraBundle” from namespace “Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle”
```

clearly the solution is to remove the duplication:

```
$foo = new TwigExtraBundle();
```

Comment: `Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class` is the line the OP is using, and it does not contain anything duplicated that is not needed

Comment: I meant somewhere else in the code, not in `bundles.php`

Comment: Why should any other part of the code cause that error?

Comment: It is NOT a case, there is no "other somewhere else in the code" usage. The problem exists right after requiring TwigExtraBundle via composer and I can confirm it is caused within `bundles.php`, although there is full FQN used (no need for import)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to close the loop on this question.

The reason why the class was still not showing up after a vendor folder deletion and fresh `composer install` was that we're using OPCache. So I needed to restart my Docker container before the class became available. (Apparently not only fully defined classes, but also *lack* of classes is OPCached. That was an interesting thing to learn.)